# How to build android things image without android thing console?

Tags: android-source, android-things

I want to build the android things image for RPi 3 with the source code which I downloaded from google. Is it possible for the current code base to build a full image ? If yes, how ?

e.g.
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-o-mr1-iot-preview-6

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Why don't you try to build the source code?

Comment: Yes, I really want to try, but I even don't know which project should I lunch ?
hikey-userdebug ? aosp_bullhead-userdebug? ...etc

Comment: @jamess Huang  I have the same question. have you tried to build it? does it work?

Answer (score 2):

Right now I don't believe you can build the full image directly as the Things Support Library doing all the I/O things is not open source.